# How to send a text to my E-Mail or to my MYSQL database without the Apple's E-Mail-App

Tags: php, mysql, xcode, swift

I created a form in the storyboard where you can type a text and then you can simply submit it to me. But i don't like my way that after pressing the submit button the E-Mail app pops up and then you'll have to send the text from there.

So how can I send the text to me right after pressing "submit" without using the E-Mail App. Are there certain php and swift examples on the internet?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the php mail function. Here is a link:

[php mail function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php)

Answer (score 0):

You can use PHPMailer, but you need to install postfix or sendmail on your server
Here is the link for PHPMailer https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

Install and Setup Postfix on Ubuntu 14.04 https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-setup-postfix-on-ubuntu-14-04
and for othe OS you can search on internet.